# Text Mining in R - How to separate sections of text based on headings for separate text analysis

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm working on around 160 separate responses to a surve. I've ran R code to produce, after cleaning, a simple wordcloud and some sensitivity analysis.

However, the template respondents have completed is split into sections. For example, the structure of the template is 
Heading 2 - Energy, then a set of questions, 
then Heading 3 - Energy Transition, another set of questions 
then Heading 4 - Consumers and questions next. 
This repeats up to 12 sections.

Instead of assessing the whole set of responses, is there a way of segmenting the responses into sections as per the topic headings within the template?

This would permit analysis within sections rather than across all topics.

I am unable to share responses due to confidentality but I can share the blank template available at https://www.economy-ni.gov.uk/energy-strategy-call-for-evidence

Dummy date in R

[50]"2. Energy in Northern Ireland"
  [51] "Q1. What lessons can we learn from elsewhere in addressing energy within an"
  [52] "overarching climate action framework?"
  [53] "Q2. What are the key considerations for decarbonising Northern Ireland’s energy"
  [54] "sector given existing linkages to other jurisdictions?"
  [55] "Q3. To what extent should Northern Ireland implement the key energy-related"
  [56] "recommendations from the CCC ‘Reducing Emissions in Northern Ireland’"
  [57] "report?"
  [58] "Q4. Do you agree with the 30-year timeframe? If not, please state your preferred"
  [59] "approach and reasons."
  [60] “Respondent response text xxxxxxxx  blahblahvlahblah”
  [61] "3. The Energy Transition in Northern Ireland"
  [62] "Q5. What are the unique characteristics of Northern Ireland that need to be"
  [63] "considered in a net zero carbon energy transition?"
  [64] "Q6. Is your organisation undertaking or planning to undertake projects to support"
  [65] "the energy transition? If so, please provide further details."
  [66] “Respondent response text xxxxxxxx  blahblahvlahblah”

Rows 60 is the text to keep for analysis for section 2 on Energy and row 66 for Section 3. Obviously the respondents text will likely be longer than a single row. Then ignore those rows with questions and headers.

All rows prior to 50 are introduction text to be ignored as well.

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: You can't share your data frame due to confidentiality -- fair enough, but could you perhaps make a toy data frame that would have the desired features and structure of the one that needs to remain private?

Comment: You could look into quanteda. This can subset a dfm or you can use corpus_segment to create several corpi based on splitting the text on a pattern match.

Comment: Thanks phiver, will explore that